# Php Upload in Linux not working

Tags: php, apache-commons-fileupload

I have this PHP upload script. I can find the JPG but it will not upload the picture. And I am trying to do this on localhost on a Linux mint machine, so my code is at /var/www/html/uploads. Here is my code for upload.php.

```
<?php
 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]   ["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
  }
 }
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" &&          $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }
 // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],      $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "    has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

And here is my code for media_upload.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>

  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the error messages from my apache2 error log. I think my problem maybe permissions or a path problem. All help greatly appreciated.

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/bedshaper_1021-36.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/uploads/upload.php on line 38, referer: http://localhost/uploads/media_upload.php

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpXeCU8c' to 'uploads/bedshaper_1021-36.jpg' in /var/www/html/uploads/upload.php on line 38, referer: http://localhost/uploads/media_upload.php

Comment: try to put a absolute path in $target_dir

Comment: Strangely you have some specific ideas about what the problem might be. Did you follow any of them?

Comment: Yes I did and none of them worked, I tried permissions and I redone the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the folder "uploads" in "/var/www/html/uploads" then it should works.
You also can change

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

to

```
$target_dir = "";
```

If you want to save the picture in "/var/www/html/uploads" you should make a direct path.

```
$target_dir = "var/www/html/uploads";
```

**EDIT**
Since your upload script is inside the upload folder you're referring to, the script doesn't find the folder.

```
$target_dir = "../uploads"
```

will also work

Comment: If his php file is in the uploads directory I am guessing it might exist

Comment: No, he has "uploads/" as dir and then he try to save the image at /var/www/html/uploads/uploads/. The PHP file is in /var/www/html/uploads/.

Comment: I am going to add this script to a shopping cart so I created a folder called products inside of uploads. And I now have my $target_dir  =     var/www/html/uploads/products. And it still does not work for me. I wonder if I  have a problem with permissions on the path from the folder where the pictures are store that I am trying to upload.

Comment: In that case try opening a console and do `sudo chmod -757 products` from the `uploads` folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
/var/www/html/uploads
```

move your both .php files outside this folder, and it will work fine, if not read below.

You don`t have to change anything in your script, just give rights to 'uploads' folder. Just tested it and it works fine.

Here you have nice instructions how to do it:
[enter link description here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/760276-how-to-manage-file-and-folder-permissions-in-linux)

Comment: No, permissions problems will not give those error:  failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: He`s probably sure by now that he have that directory link right, next step is giving rights to folder.

Comment: The problem is he's referring to the same folder which the script is in. The folder doesn't exist within itself

Comment: I am going to add this script to a shopping cart so I created a folder called products inside of uploads. And I now have my $target_dir = var/www/html/uploads/products. And it still does not work for me. I wonder if I have a problem with permissions on the path from the folder where the pictures are store that I am trying to upload.

Comment: Make your $target_dir path with ' dirname(__FILE__) ', var_dump it, and just glue the rest it will make you sure that your path is right. Then just give the right to the folder that you are storing your uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by renaming the folder where I wanted the files to products and resetting permissions on the products folder and on upload.php I changed tar_direct = /var/www/html/uploads/products and everything is working fine. Thank you for the advice problem solved.